# select row from a table based on entry of other table and delete data from other table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my database like this:

```
 Table-1                          Table-2

 id Name                          id  Name 
 1  A                              1  D-a
 2  B                              2  D-b
 3  C                              3  D-c 
 4  D
```

I want a query which gives me output such as

```
A B C D-a D-b D-c
```

i.e. check if there is entry of D in Table-1 if there is then select all entries of Table-2 and remove D from output

Comment: this one `check if there is entry of D in Table-1 if there is then select all entries of Table-2 and remove D from output` is not clear.

Comment: give the column name in your result to understand your output and we make query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best answer to your question, but it can help you:

```
Select Distinct Table1.name
From Table1, Table2
WHERE Not Table2.name Like Table1.name+'%'
UNION All
Select Distinct Table2.name
From Table1, Table2
WHERE Table2.name Like Table1.name+'%'
```

Now you have your results in a column.
If you want to have them in a row follow this question:
[Concatenate many rows into a single text string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/4519059)